# How to test styles and media queries rendered by a React component with Jest and/or Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` to develop a framework that my company will use internally. We need to create new responsive components and when I test this in a browser, I can see how the rendered component changes its background-color when I resize the window. I'm trying to achieve the same programatically and test the functionality with Jest and/or Enzyme, but I've got no success so far. Anybody knows?

This is the code for the component:

```
const Component = styled.div`
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;

    background-color: purple;

    @media (max-width: ${DESKTOP}px) {
        background-color: purple;
    }

    @media (max-width: ${TABLET}px) {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    @media (max-width: ${MOBILE}px) {
        background-color: red;
    }
`
```

I wrote the following tests using `toHaveStyleRule` from the `jest-styled-components` package. Tests are passing because they effectively verify that 'background-color' is 'red' for the MOBILE media query, and so on.

```
expect(<Component />).toHaveStyleRule(
    { 'background-color': 'red' },
    { media: `(max-width: ${MOBILE}px)` }
)

expect(<Component />).toHaveStyleRule(
    { 'background-color': 'yellow' },
    { media: `(max-width: ${TABLET}px)` }
)

expect(<Component />).toHaveStyleRule(
    { 'background-color': 'blue' },
    { media: `(max-width: ${DESKTOP}px)` }
)
```

However, tests fail if I resize the window doing `window.resizeTo(250, 250)`, because I expect the component to look red and instead, 'background-color' always seem to be 'purple'

For resizing window, I use  and I've been trying this snippet with JSDOM: https://gist.github.com/javierarques/d95948ac7e9ddc8097612866ecc63a4b

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recreate this locally, but what I realized was the first 2 `expect`s passed, whereas the last one did not. That was because the `DESKTOP` media query block is setting the `background-color` to "purple", whereas the `expect` is looking for "blue".

```
    background-color: purple;

    @media (max-width: ${DESKTOP}px) {
        background-color: purple;
    }
```

```
expect(<Component />).toHaveStyleRule(
    { 'background-color': 'blue' },
    { media: `(max-width: ${DESKTOP}px)` }
)
```

Let me know if that's not the problem you are actually seeing.